# Eager map in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

In Python the `map` function is lazy, but most often I need an eager map.

For example, trying to slice a map object results in an error:

```
>>>> map(abs, [3, -1, -4, 1])[1:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable (key slice(1, None, None))
```

I guess I need to implement an eager map myself, so I wonder whether there's a standard way of doing that in Python.

I managed to implement it in a few different ways, but I'm not sure what alternative should be preferred. I'm asking for both CPython and for PyPy3, if the answer varies depending on the Python implementation, I'd prefer to know about all relevant options.

These are my implementations:

```
def eager_map_impl0(f, *collections):
  return list(map(f, *collections))

def eager_map_impl1(f, *collections):
  return [x for x in map(f, *collections)]

def eager_map_impl2(f, *collections):
  return [*map(f, *collections)]

def eager_map_impl3(f, *collections):
  return [f(*x) for x in zip(*collections)]
```

Usage example:

```
>>>> eager_map_impl0(abs, [3, -1, -4, 1])[1:]
[1, 4, 1]
>>>> eager_map_impl1(abs, [3, -1, -4, 1])[1:]
[1, 4, 1]
>>>> eager_map_impl2(abs, [3, -1, -4, 1])[1:]
[1, 4, 1]
>>>> eager_map_impl3(abs, [3, -1, -4, 1])[1:]
[1, 4, 1]
```

Regarding the duplicate vote, the linked question and some of its answers are interesting, but not an answer here, I think. I already know I want to use `map`, not list comprehensions; so I was hoping someone would say what is the most performant implementation in CPython vs Pypy as an answer here.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252585/discussion-on-question-by-user2373145-eager-map-in-python); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `list(map(...))`, as in your first example, is enough for what you want, and you don't even  need another function just for wrapping that - as its intent is obvious.

The performance difference of using a list vs a comprehension in this case should be minimal, but with advantages on the list side, as no Python VM ops need to be executed - the list builder will call `__next__` in the map iterator directly in native code.  For Pypy that is unpredictable since for sequences long enough to be meaningfull, JIT will be triggered, and it may have ways of its own. (anyway, the difference should not be relevant)

Now, at times, one might want to just apply a `map` and *not* store the results, in the cases the mapping function performs I/O or have other side-effects. In this case, the best-performant approach is little documented: the `collections.deque` structure, with a maxlen of 0 is actually internally optimized to consume all items in an iterator, and would process all your items:

```
from collections import deque

...

deque(map(function, items), maxlen=0)  # <- process everyone and throws away the return values.
```

Comment: If you show alternatives like deque, maybe also show an alternative for their example: islice.

Comment: The deque trick (for applying map for its side-effects) is neat and that's exactly what I was looking for today, thanks! One question though: is it faster than just writing a for-in loop?

Comment: Yes, the deque trick should be slightly faster - more certainly up to Python 3.10. From 3.11 on, the difference should be smaller due to language optimizations.